# how to Mingw compiler compatible with Qt 4.8.5

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, mingw32

i have problem when i want to compile progrmmes under Qt 4.8.5 and Mingw compiler

i tried many version of Mingw ( v 4.5.0 till 4.8 ) but alway i get the same error

```
c:\Qt\4.8.5\lib\libqtmaind.a(qtmain_win.o):-1: In function `WinMain@16':
c:\iwmake\build_mingw_opensource\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp:93: erreur : undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
c:\iwmake\build_mingw_opensource\src\winmain\qtmain_win.cpp:135: erreur : undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
c:\Qt\4.8.5\lib\libqtmaind.a(qtmain_win.o):-1: In function `ZN7QVectorIPcE7reallocEii':
c:\iwmake\build_mingw_opensource\src\corelib\tools\qvector.h:512: erreur : undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
c:\iwmake\build_mingw_opensource\src\corelib\tools\qvector.h:513: erreur : undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
qtmain_win.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
:-1: erreur : collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I've been using GCC 4.4 without problems https://code.google.com/p/psi-dev/downloads/detail?name=MinGW-gcc-4.4.0-2.7z

Comment: this copy of Mingw is working for me thank's a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are not using mingw, but mingw-w64. mingw is more or less dead nowadays.

My recommendation is to use the mingw-w64 packaged in the latest Qt SDK. There is a Qt-builds project as well other than the mingw builds. That is run by the mingw-builds team. They have proper scripts to build all of Qt, QtCreator, and so forth.

Here you can find them (develop branch):

https://github.com/Alexpux/Qt-builds/tree/develop

That being said, you can grab the latest for today with mingw, too:

https://code.google.com/p/psi-dev/downloads/detail?name=MinGW-gcc-4.4.0-2.7z